# Any sudo command on Linux gives “Exec format error”

Tags: linux, sudo, raspberry-pi

Any time I use a command involving sudo, I get the error `-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`, even for commands like `sudo reboot` or `sudo ls`, `sudo cd`, things that have nothing to do with executables and it's really irritating. It seemingly came up out of nowhere after trying to reboot by Raspberry Pi running Linux and I haven't seen any issues related.

Comment: Check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/60720049/9235408 Most probably the architecture is different.

Answer (score 5):

The error isn't about `reboot` or `ls`, but about `sudo` itself. The error message clearly shows it's from Bash, and mentions the file in question (`/usr/bin/sudo`).

The error "Exec format error" is error code `ENOEXEC`, which is returned by the `exec*()` syscalls when

> An executable is not in a recognized format, is for the wrong architecture, or has some other format error that means it cannot be executed.

There's something wrong with your `sudo` binary. It's either corrupted somehow, or you have the binary for the wrong machine (e.g. an x86 binary on ARM). `file /usr/bin/sudo` may be able to tell you something (if you have `file`), compare with e.g. the output of `file /bin/ls`, assuming that works.

Also, for what it's worth: everything you run through sudo has to do with executables. `reboot` is probably `/sbin/reboot`, an executable binary file; `ls` is probably `/bin/ls`, an executable binary file. And `sudo cd` would probably give an error, since most Linux distributions don't have `cd` binary (it would be next to useless).

Answer (score 0):

I got the mentioned error message, because my *bash script*-based *askpass* executable was missing the *hashbang* marker.

Adding

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to the beginning to the script (and maybe additionally making the script executable with `chmod +x`) resolved the issue.